# React native hooks and calling API with pagination

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-hooks

I have a react native application where I'm calling a graphQL API.  The GraphQL queries are structured to support a pagination operations.

The query is shown below. I can pass both size and skip variables to the query to allow it to retrieve data for a given number of records. For simplicity, I've ignored the userData because it's not important.

```
const paginationQuery = `{
      actualDataByUser${skip ? '(where: {size: '+size+', start_position:' + skip + '})' : ''} {
        data {
          .... (IGNORE THIS)
        }
      }
    }`;
```

I'm trying to understand if hooks make sense here with different `size` and `skip` parameters? For example I can create a function `actualDataByUser` like this which runs the above query and gets the first 100 records.

```
const getAllRecords = async (obj={}) => {
  return actualDataByUser(obj);
}

The hook below will retrieve the first 100 records starting from 0.

export default function RecordScreen() {
  
  const [recordList, setRecordList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
      const receivedRecords = getAllRecords({skip: 0, size: 100}).then(res => {
      setRecordList(receivedRecords);
  }, []);

  
}
```

However, I'm trying to understand the best way to increment `skip` each time to allow it to keep streaming the data back.

Comment: I researched this further and understand how this should.  I need to tie it to user action like scrolling or search which should then call another method, e.g. fetchNextData().  It will then continue to retrieve more records.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code this way to prevent errors

```
export default function RecordScreen() {
  
  const [recordList, setRecordList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
      const receivedRecords = getAllRecords({skip: 0, size: 100}).then(res => {});
      setRecordList(receivedRecords);
  }, []);
}
```